# JsonHttpRH: onSuccess(int, Header[], JSONArray) was not overriden, but callback was received?

Tags: java, android

My app is supposed to show data from CoinGecko API, here's what I tried but can't get it to work.

API Service:

```
public class CoinGeckoService {
    public static final String COINGECKO_GLOBAL_URL = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/global";

    private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    public static void getGlobalData(AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            URIBuilder query = new URIBuilder(COINGECKO_GLOBAL_URL);
            query.addParameters(params);
            client.get(query.toString(), responseHandler);
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException e){
            Log.e("URISyntaxException", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Model:

```
public class GlobalData implements Parcelable {
    private String total_market_cap;
    private String active_cryptocurrencies;
    private String markets;
    private String total_volume;
    private String market_cap_percentage;

    public GlobalData(Parcel in){
        String[] data = new String[5];

        in.readStringArray(data);
        this.total_market_cap = data[0];
        this.active_cryptocurrencies = data[1];
        this.markets = data[2];
        this.total_volume = data[3];
        this.market_cap_percentage = data[4];
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<GlobalData> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<GlobalData>() {
        @Override
        public GlobalData createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new GlobalData(source);
        }
        @Override
        public GlobalData[] newArray(int size) {
            return new GlobalData[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeStringArray(new String[]{
                this.total_market_cap,
                this.active_cryptocurrencies,
                this.markets,
                this.total_volume,
                this.market_cap_percentage
        });
    }

    public String getTotalMarketCap() {
        return total_market_cap;
    }

    public String getActiveCurrenices() {
        return active_cryptocurrencies;
    }

    public String getMarkets() {
        return markets;
    }

    public String getTotalVolume() {
        return total_volume;
    }

    public String getMarketCapPercent() {
        return market_cap_percentage;
    }

}
```

Lastly, this method is inside my fragment:

```
    public void getGlobalData() {

        CoinGeckoService.getGlobalData(new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
                GlobalData[] result = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), GlobalData[].class);

                for (GlobalData node : result) {
                    marketCapData.setText(node.getTotalMarketCap());
                    Log.d("response_", "" +node.getTotalMarketCap());
                }
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject response) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }
```

But It doesn't seem to work, and log says: JsonHttpRH: onSuccess(int, Header[], JSONArray) was not overriden, but callback was received.

This is the response data from the API: https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/global

Answer (score 1):

try to use retrofit2.Add these dependencies into gradle.
Using retrofit is the best way for fetching data from remote source.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
```

then create an APIURL class which includes your base url

```
  public class APIUrl {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.coingecko.com/";
}
```

after that create an APIService class which includes your get parameters.My data should be generated from this website. 
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

```
public interface APIService {
    @GET("api/v3/global")
    Call<MyData> getList();
}
```

Lastly fetch your data like this.

```
 public void getData() {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(APIUrl.BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();

            APIService apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
            Call<MyData> call = apiService.getData();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<VeriListem>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call< MyData > call, Response< MyData > response) {
                   // this gives you all data as MyData type and do your operation here
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<MyData> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("error", t.getMessage().toString());
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: For creating MyData paste your json response http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org and select Source type: JSON, Annotation style:GSON.